# User inputs Integer, when calling an array with this Int always returns 0?

Tags: java, arrays, input, integer

So I want to make the user input a number; which turns into an integer. This should look in an array and call up the number, for some reason, the int always turns to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the whole code; the first 20 lines are where the problem's at.

```
 import java.util.*;

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // data tabellen
        int[] dag = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};


            //input begin       
            int datumbegmax = 0;
            System.out.println("Startdate in month? From 1 to 12.");
            int maandbeg = input.nextInt(); 
            dag[maandbeg] = datumbegmax;
            System.out.println(dag[maandbeg]);
            if (maandbeg < 1 || maandbeg > 12) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, Start over.");   }
            System.out.println("Startdate in days? From 1 to 31.");
            int datumbeg = input.nextInt();
            if (datumbeg < 1 || datumbeg > datumbegmax) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, Start over.");
             }
            int urenbeg = 0 ;
            System.out.println("Starting time in hours? From 0 to 24.");
            urenbeg = input.nextInt();
            if (urenbeg < 0 || urenbeg > 24) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, Start over.");
            }
            int minutenbeg = 0 ; 
            System.out.println("Starting time in minutes? From 0 to 60.");
            minutenbeg = input.nextInt();
            if (minutenbeg < 0 || minutenbeg > 60) {
                System.out.println("ERROR,  Start over.");
            }

            //input eind
            int datumeindmax = 0;
            System.out.println("Einddatum in maand? Van 1 tot 12.");
            int maandeind = dag[input.nextInt()];
            dag[maandeind] = datumeindmax;
            if (maandeind < 1 || maandeind > 12) {
                System.out.println("FOUT, Begin opnieuw.");
            }
            System.out.println("Einddatum in dagen? Van 1 tot 31.");
            int datumeind = input.nextInt();
            if (datumeind < 1 || datumeind > datumeindmax) {
                System.out.println("FOUT, Begin opnieuw.");
            }
            int ureneind;
            System.out.println("Eindtijd in uren? Van 0 tot 24.");
            ureneind = input.nextInt();
            if (ureneind < 0 || ureneind > 24) {
                System.out.println("FOUT, Begin opnieuw.");
            }
            int minuteneind;
            System.out.println("Eindtijd in minuten? Van 0 tot 60.");
            minuteneind = input.nextInt();
            if (minuteneind < 0 || minuteneind > 60) {
                System.out.println("FOUT, Begin opnieuw.");
            }
            int maand = maandeind - maandbeg;
            int datum = datumeind - datumbeg;
            if (datum < 0){datum = datum + dag[maandbeg];}
            int uren = ureneind - urenbeg;
            if (datum > 0) {uren = uren + datum*24;}
            int minuten = minuteneind - minutenbeg;
            if (minuten < 0){
                minuten = minuten + 60;
                uren = uren - 1;
            }
            System.out.println("Total time:  "+datum+" days, "+uren+" hours and "+minuten+" minutes.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Localize and compress your code before posting.

Comment: @zvzdhk The code is clearly *localized* :D

Comment: @KennyTM I sure everybody get what I mean :)

Comment: Still too _local_? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do

```
dag[maandbeg] = datumbegmax;
```

which overwrites the array value with 0, because of int `datumbegmax = 0;`

of course, `System.out.println(dag[maandbeg]);` prints 0 then